Implementing an Enum as a PostgreSQL Column using SeaORM
I'm currently stuck on how to make one of my columns be an Enum of different payment types (Cash, Credit, Debit, etc.)
This is what I currently have for the table where manager is a reference to SchemaManager
       manager
            .create_table(
                Table::create()
                    .table(Orders::Table)
                    .if_not_exists()
                    (Creating a couple other columns)...
    // This line    .col(ColumnDef::new(Orders::PaymentType).enumeration(**PaymentOptions**, PaymentOptions::**iter()**).not_null())
                    (Just creating some more columns)...
                    .to_owned()
            )
            .await?;

In a seperate file, I have my enum PaymentOptions as such:
use strum_macros::EnumIter;

#[derive(Debug, EnumIter)]
pub enum PaymentOptions {
    Cash,
    Credit, 
    Debit, 
    Voucher,
}

I get 2 compiler-errors (under each of the bold sections), with the first (under PaymentOptions) being:
expected value, found enum PaymentOptionsrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
mod.rs(6, 1): the enum is defined here
m20220101_000001_create_table.rs(24, 74): you might have meant to use one of the following enum variants: 
m20220101_000001_create_table::PaymentOptions::Cash, 
m20220101_000001_create_table::PaymentOptions::Credit, 
m20220101_000001_create_table::PaymentOptions::Debit, 
m20220101_000001_create_table::PaymentOptions::Voucher

And the second being:
no variant or associated item named `iter` found for enum `PaymentOptions` in the current scope
items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scoperustcClick for full compiler diagnostic

mod.rs(6, 1): variant or associated item `iter` not found for this enum

m20220101_000001_create_table.rs(1, 1): trait `IntoEnumIterator` which provides `iter` is implemented but 
not in scope; perhaps you want to import it: `use strum::IntoEnumIterator;`

I've looked into active_enum and ActiveEnumValue but I don't understand the documentation behind it enough to determine whether I can actually use these as a solution or how to implement them.
Maybe I can also continue using .enumeration:
**Documentation Excerpt**
pub fn enumeration<N, S, V>(&mut self, name: N, variants: V) -> &mut ColumnDef
where
    N: IntoIden,
    S: IntoIden,
    V: IntoIterator<Item = S>,
Set column type as enum.

But its unclear what it really wants passed in as a parameter to me.

The error message says "trait IntoEnumIterator which provides iter is implemented but
not in scope; perhaps you want to import it: use strum::IntoEnumIterator;" Did you try that? Did that not help?

I'm not intimately familiar with sea-orm, I cannot find things like Table, .col, or .enumeration in the latest sea-orm docs to help you out. What version are you using? Or is some of this from a different crate?

Either way, an enum type is not ever valid as a parameter. If the parameter is called "name" perhaps it wants it as a string? i.e. "PaymentOptions"

Yeah the sea-orm docs aren't explained really clearly, it kind of just throws a bunch of already implemented code at you and expects you to figure out how it works by yourself, I ended up finding a solution though after a couple hours of playing around with it, I'll post the solution in a minute for anybody else facing a similar issue.

Overall, @Stefanov.sm is right though, using native SQL would have been much simpler and effective but I didn't have a choice in this case, I had a professor who wanted us to learn ORM syntax and didn't give us the option

After digging around a while, I found there's a couple ways to do it, and you really just have to try each of them because some of them don't work for no real apparent reason sometimes and it also depends on the database you're using (mySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.), but this here should explain most of it: https://www.sea-ql.org/SeaORM/docs/next/generate-entity/enumeration/
I found the easiest way (using PostgreSQL), was to create the enum like so:
#[derive(DeriveIden)]
#[sea_orm(enum_name = "payment_options")]
pub enum PaymentOptions {
    #[sea_orm(iden = "payment_options")]
    Enum,
    #[sea_orm(iden = "cash")]
    Cash,
    #[sea_orm(iden = "credit")]
    Credit, 
    #[sea_orm(iden = "debit")]
    Debit, 
    #[sea_orm(iden = "voucher")]
    Voucher,
} 

Where the most important part is just to make sure you include enum_name and DeriveIden.
Then you can go ahead and create it as a new type like this:
        manager
            .create_type(
                Type::create()
                    .as_enum(PaymentOptions::Enum)
                    .values(
                        [
                            PaymentOptions::Cash, 
                            PaymentOptions::Credit, 
                            PaymentOptions::Debit, 
                            PaymentOptions::Voucher
                        ]
                    )
                    .to_owned(),
            )
            .await?;

There are other ways to create the new type but this is the most straightforward and reliable method in my opinion.
Then I just needed to implement it while creating the table like this:
.col(ColumnDef::new(Orders::PaymentType).custom(PaymentOptions::Enum).not_null())

For anyone else with the same issue, I'd recommend just reading through the documentation thouroughly from the link I attached as other methods may work better for you

Your use of a dummy Enum variant looks dubious and is not demonstrated in the link you've shared. It looks like the key is DeriveActiveEnum which allows you to use ::name() and create_enum_from_active_enum.

https://github.com/SeaQL/sea-orm/blob/master/sea-orm-migration/tests/common/migration/m20220118_000004_create_tea_enum.rs

@kmdreko This was hidden in a "Full example" link within the link I sent, I should've clarified that's where I got it from but as I mentioned before the seaORM docs aren't clearly explained and everything is kind of scattered all over.
I tried using the DeriveActiveEnum and ::name() earlier but I would still get an error saying PaymentOptions can't use ::name() and this Solution with the "Enum" variant was the only thing that worked for me.
I wouldn't recommend it as the first thing you should try, but in my case no other solutions in the documentation would run without error

Thanks for the link and follow-up. That is very strange, I wonder if this is something that can still be improved if 1.0 hasn't been released yet.
